# How can I listen specifically to ContextRefreshedEvent on Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I am sending a `POST` request to refresh my Spring application using Spring Cloud Server. However when I listen to the `ContextRefreshedEvent`, the event is also published at startup. Same thing for the `EnvironmentChangeEvent`.

How can I listen to an event that is published only when I trigger refresh on the `ApplicationContext` through a `POST` request?

Comment: you could set a special variable in the controller to check if the event was sent by POST request, not from startup

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Spring Cloud **Config** Server and post to `/refresh`?

Comment: `EnvironmentChangeEvent` with an empty set of keys is published at startup. What are you trying to accomplish on `/refresh`?